# Adding newer prices to old one which builds up to the total price in a textbox in C#

Tags: c#, textbox

OK THIS IS WHAT HAPPENED:

```
      decimal Price = 0m;
      string TotalPrice = "";

     if (boxes[i].Checked == true)
    {
  select += SecondMenuList[i].ToString() + "   :  " + "\t\t" +
   Check[i].ToString("c") + "\r\n";//THIS GOES TO THE MESSAGE BOX

    Price += Check[i];

   TotalPrice = Price.ToString("c");//THIS ONLY SHOWS CURRENT PRICE VALUES

   TotalSales.Text = TotalPrice;//THIS IS NOT NECESSARY, DON'T EVEN DO IT YET.

     txtTotalPrice.Text = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalPrice.Text)? Price:  

  (Int32.Parse(txtTotalPrice.Text) + Price)).ToString("DON'T ADD CURRENCY
   FORMAT");//SO THAT THE STRING CAN BE CONVERTED BACK TO DECIMAL
    //TO ADD THE NEW Price TO IT, RECONVERT TO STRING AND DISPLAY IN THE
   //TotalSales TEXTBOX
    }

WHEN YOU DECLARE DECIMALS WHOSE VALUES WOULD BE ASSIGNED TO EACH OTHER, LEAVE 
ALL OF   THEM IN THE SAME FORMAT. EG: decimal TotalPrice = 0m; decimal Price = 0m;
NOT decimal TotalPrice = .00m; AND decimal Price = 0m;
```

---

********PLEASE THE SECOND QUESTION IS STILL HANGIN*****************************

sealed class SerialPortDataRead//for serial port communication
        {

```
        // Create the serial port with basic settings

        private readonly SerialPort port = new SerialPort("COM5", 9600, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        private readonly Form1 form1;

        public SerialPortDataRead(Form1 form1)
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization
            this.form1 = form1;
        }

        public SerialPortDataRead()
        {
            // TODO: Complete member initialization

        }

        private void Serial()
        {
            //beep the default system sound to indicate an incoming data
            SystemSounds.Beep.Play();

            // Attach a method to be called when there is data waiting in 
            //the port's buffer

            port.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;

            // Begin communications

            port.Open();

            // Enter an application loop to keep this thread alive

            Application.Run();

           }

        private void port_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
        { // Arrange the incoming data in an array

            string[] PortVal = { port.ReadExisting() };

            double[] Check = new double[6]
        {120, 120, 100, 100, 150, 100};//this is the price array

            string[] SecondMenuList = new string[6]
        {"Screw Driver", "Tape", "Glue", "Marker", "Halogen"};//this the mainarray

            string FirstSelection = "";
            string value = "";
            using (Form1 frm = new Form1())
            {
                string[] c = { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
                for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
                    if (PortVal[i] == SecondMenuList[i])//this is where the 

                   //problem lies
```

// I want to only compare the first three letters of each elements in PortVal at

//any index with the first three letters of the elements in the

//SecondMenulist array. but i can only compare the elements

//what should i do here PLEASE?

```
                 {
                        FirstSelection += String.Format("{0}\t:{1:c}\r\n", 

                        SecondMenuList[i], Check[i]);

                        value = Check[i].ToString("c");

                         if (PortVal.Contains(c[i]))

                           {
```

//after the comparison, if there is any match, add the matched element

//in the SecondMenuList array to the DataGrid Table (named Table)

```
                          this.form1._names.Add("TABLE");
                            this.form1._dataArray.Add(new string[] { c[i] });
                        }
                        this.form1._names.Add("ITEM");
                        this.form1._dataArray.Add(new string[] { SecondMenuList[i] });

                        this.form1._names.Add("PRICE");
                        this.form1._dataArray.Add(new string[] { 
                        Check[i].ToString("c") });
                    }
                frm.txtTotalSales.Text = value;
            }
            DateTime Date = new DateTime();
            Date = DateTime.Now;
            PrinterHelper.SendStringToPrinter(String.Format("Order(s)\r\n\n\t{0}\t:{1}

                \r\n\n\t{2}",
                                 FirstSelection,
                                   value,
                                    Date));

        }
    }

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();


        dataGridView1.DataSource = GetResultsTable();

    }

    public Form1(TextBox txtTotalSales)
    {
        // TODO: Complete member initialization
        this.txtTotalSales = txtTotalSales;
    }

    private static SerialPortDataRead port_DataReceived()
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public DataTable GetResultsTable()
    {
        DataTable Table = new DataTable();
        for (int i = 0; i < this._dataArray.Count; i++)
        {
            string name = this._names[i];
            Table.Columns.Add(name);
            List<object> objectNumbers = new List<object>();
            foreach (string number in this._dataArray[i])
            {
                objectNumbers.Add((object)number);
            }
            while (Table.Rows.Count < objectNumbers.Count)
            {
                Table.Rows.Add();
            }
            for (int a = 0; a < objectNumbers.Count; a++)
            {
                Table.Rows[a][i] = objectNumbers[a];
            }
        }
        return Table;
    }
```

Comment: I am completely confused by your question.  Please provide examples of the data coming in and how you want it to appear in the end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
if (boxes[i].Checked == true)
{
select += SecondMenuList[i].ToString() + "   :  " + "\t\t" +
    Check[i].ToString("c") + "\r\n";

Price += Check[i];

TotalPrice = Price.ToString("c");
txtTotalPrice.Text = (String.IsNullOrEmpty(txtTotalPrice.Text)?0:(Int32.Parse(txtTotalPrice.Text)+TotalPrice)).ToString();
}
```

Comment: @ Microprocessor, formatexception, input string was not in the correct format. please is there any other way out?

Comment: I edited my answer to check if your text box is empty then add zero, you can make this check by any other way you want.Note that text box must contains numbers only otherwise that exception will be fired again and again.

Comment: thanks alot. but this time, it runs for the first time to display zero and throws formatEcption. this driving me nuts

Comment: what does the textbox value look like?does it contain characters?

Comment: i've finally solved the problem. thanks a lot for your concern

Comment: you are welcome.could you share how you solved your problem and if you used any approach mentioned in any answer, please check it as answer for your question.that will give you more reputations.

Comment: i've edited the question. i used your approach with little modifications. you're good.

Answer (score 0):

TestBox.Text is a string. When u do +=, it means appending/concatenating and not adding.

Comment: please what should i do then?

Comment: you first convert the value of text to string, use Int32.TryParse and then add the values. Then replace back to textbox.Text